# Apply a style to an image which overlays a transparent png

Tags: css, image, styles, png, overlay

I'm trying to create a style that a client can select in the dropdown TinyMCE Wordpress visual editor which will overlay a transparent png onto a selected image.

The png has a scuffed border, so I essentially need to overlay this border png onto an existing photo/image.

This is easy enough for me to do having the two images (both the picture and the png border) in two separate divs and then putting one on top of the other, with different z-indexes.

However, I'd like to create a style which will effect this, and no matter what I try, I can't get the png to appear!

Here's the style I've applied to the image in the drop-down:

```
.roughedges {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/edges.png');
width: 210px;
height: 157px;
z-index:10;
}
```

No cigar.  The png won't show.

Any ideas???

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: No matter how you approach this, your image will need to be wrapped in a block or inline-block element.  If this is not possible, you will need a JavaScript or jQuery assisted solution to create the necessary elements around the image.  This can't be done using CSS rules applied only to the `img` tag.

Comment: Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).